# Not getting how to sort multidimensional array by a specific key in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sorting

it might be a duplicate of question but not getting how to do in my case.

i have a array

```
array([status]=>array([0]=>array([time][id])
                array([1]=>array([time][id])
```

tried `krsort($array[status]);`

but got sorting on id where as i want to do sorting according to time in descending order.

Comment: What does your array contain?

Comment: [time=> timestamp(string)]  [id=> integer]

Comment: Why did the solutions in duplicates not work for you?